# How to Connect Db2 Luw from python using SSL

Tags: python, db2

I am trying to connect the db2 mainframe from a python code and using ibm_db from MAC OS X

```
import ibm_db as db

conn = db.connect("DRIVER=/Users/guilhermemarcondes/Downloads/datavirtuality-jdbc_2.1.0.1.jar;DATABASE=DB2CPIDC;HOSTNAME=xxx;PORT=xxx;Security=SSL;SslServerCertificate=xxxxx/certreq.arm;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=test;PWD=xxxx;", "", "")

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM teste where iorder = 'B6040353' ")
for r in cursor.fetchall():
    print(r)
```

However when I try to run I get this error message :

Exception:

> [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10013N  The specified library "GSKit Error: 2"
>   could not be loaded.  SQLSTATE=42724 SQLCODE=-10013

Could someone please help me ?

Thank so much

Comment: Suggest you start by using the IBM supplied jdbc driver (not the datavirtuality one as shown in your question).

Comment: Separately, your subject line has "Connect Db2 Luw", but question specifies "Db2 mainframe".  Edit your question or subject  to specify whether you are connecting to Db2-Z/os or Db2-LUW and also use the appropriate TAG.

Comment: Also, edit your question to show if you made any changes to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of your certificate file. It should have at least one section starting with

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

I got the same, unhelpful `"GSKit Error: 2"` when the contents of my certificate file was base64-encoded, so that GSKit couldn't load the certificate.